# Round robin scheduler C implementation for Multipath Tcp / linux kernel

Tags: c, tcp, linux-kernel, scheduling, mptcp

i am trying to understand the round robin code for Mulltipath tcp scheduling . it is available here
https://github.com/multipath-tcp/mptcp/blob/mptcp_v0.95/net/mptcp/mptcp_rr.c
i had too much difficulties since there is no documentation
here is the code

```
 `/* MPTCP Scheduler module selector. Highly inspired by tcp_cong.c */

#include <linux/module.h>
#include <net/mptcp.h>

static unsigned char num_segments __read_mostly = 1;
module_param(num_segments, byte, 0644);
MODULE_PARM_DESC(num_segments, "The number of consecutive segments that are part of a burst");

static bool cwnd_limited __read_mostly = 1;
module_param(cwnd_limited, bool, 0644);
MODULE_PARM_DESC(cwnd_limited, "if set to 1, the scheduler tries to fill the congestion-window on all subflows");

struct rrsched_priv {
    unsigned char quota;
};

static struct rrsched_priv *rrsched_get_priv(const struct tcp_sock *tp)
{
    return (struct rrsched_priv *)&tp->mptcp->mptcp_sched[0];
}

/* If the sub-socket sk available to send the skb? */
static bool mptcp_rr_is_available(const struct sock *sk, const struct sk_buff *skb,
                  bool zero_wnd_test, bool cwnd_test)
{
    const struct tcp_sock *tp = tcp_sk(sk);
    unsigned int space, in_flight;

    /* Set of states for which we are allowed to send data */
    if (!mptcp_sk_can_send(sk))
        return false;

    /* We do not send data on this subflow unless it is
     * fully established, i.e. the 4th ack has been received.
     */
    if (tp->mptcp->pre_established)
        return false;

    if (tp->pf)
        return false;

    if (inet_csk(sk)->icsk_ca_state == TCP_CA_Loss) {
        /* If SACK is disabled, and we got a loss, TCP does not exit
         * the loss-state until something above high_seq has been acked.
         * (see tcp_try_undo_recovery)
         *
         * high_seq is the snd_nxt at the moment of the RTO. As soon
         * as we have an RTO, we won't push data on the subflow.
         * Thus, snd_una can never go beyond high_seq.
         */
        if (!tcp_is_reno(tp))
            return false;
        else if (tp->snd_una != tp->high_seq)
            return false;
    }

    if (!tp->mptcp->fully_established) {
        /* Make sure that we send in-order data */
        if (skb && tp->mptcp->second_packet &&
            tp->mptcp->last_end_data_seq != TCP_SKB_CB(skb)->seq)
            return false;
    }

    if (!cwnd_test)
        goto zero_wnd_test;

    in_flight = tcp_packets_in_flight(tp);
    /* Not even a single spot in the cwnd */
    if (in_flight >= tp->snd_cwnd)
        return false;

    /* Now, check if what is queued in the subflow's send-queue
     * already fills the cwnd.
     */
    space = (tp->snd_cwnd - in_flight) * tp->mss_cache;

    if (tp->write_seq - tp->snd_nxt > space)
        return false;

zero_wnd_test:
    if (zero_wnd_test && !before(tp->write_seq, tcp_wnd_end(tp)))
        return false;

    return true;
}

/* Are we not allowed to reinject this skb on tp? */
static int mptcp_rr_dont_reinject_skb(const struct tcp_sock *tp, const struct sk_buff *skb)
{
    /* If the skb has already been enqueued in this sk, try to find
     * another one.
     */
    return skb &&
        /* Has the skb already been enqueued into this subsocket? */
        mptcp_pi_to_flag(tp->mptcp->path_index) & TCP_SKB_CB(skb)->path_mask;
}

/* We just look for any subflow that is available */
static struct sock *rr_get_available_subflow(struct sock *meta_sk,
                         struct sk_buff *skb,
                         bool zero_wnd_test)
{
    const struct mptcp_cb *mpcb = tcp_sk(meta_sk)->mpcb;
    struct sock *sk = NULL, *bestsk = NULL, *backupsk = NULL;
    struct mptcp_tcp_sock *mptcp;

    /* Answer data_fin on same subflow!!! */
    if (meta_sk->sk_shutdown & RCV_SHUTDOWN &&
        skb && mptcp_is_data_fin(skb)) {
        mptcp_for_each_sub(mpcb, mptcp) {
            sk = mptcp_to_sock(mptcp);
            if (tcp_sk(sk)->mptcp->path_index == mpcb->dfin_path_index &&
                mptcp_rr_is_available(sk, skb, zero_wnd_test, true))
                return sk;
        }
    }

    /* First, find the best subflow */
    mptcp_for_each_sub(mpcb, mptcp) {
        struct tcp_sock *tp;

        sk = mptcp_to_sock(mptcp);
        tp = tcp_sk(sk);

        if (!mptcp_rr_is_available(sk, skb, zero_wnd_test, true))
            continue;

        if (mptcp_rr_dont_reinject_skb(tp, skb)) {
            backupsk = sk;
            continue;
        }

        bestsk = sk;
    }

    if (bestsk) {
        sk = bestsk;
    } else if (backupsk) {
        /* It has been sent on all subflows once - let's give it a
         * chance again by restarting its pathmask.
         */
        if (skb)
            TCP_SKB_CB(skb)->path_mask = 0;
        sk = backupsk;
    }

    return sk;
}

/* Returns the next segment to be sent from the mptcp meta-queue.
 * (chooses the reinject queue if any segment is waiting in it, otherwise,
 * chooses the normal write queue).
 * Sets *@reinject to 1 if the returned segment comes from the
 * reinject queue. Sets it to 0 if it is the regular send-head of the meta-sk,
 * and sets it to -1 if it is a meta-level retransmission to optimize the
 * receive-buffer.
 */
static struct sk_buff *__mptcp_rr_next_segment(const struct sock *meta_sk, int *reinject)
{
    const struct mptcp_cb *mpcb = tcp_sk(meta_sk)->mpcb;
    struct sk_buff *skb = NULL;

    *reinject = 0;

    /* If we are in fallback-mode, just take from the meta-send-queue */
    if (mpcb->infinite_mapping_snd || mpcb->send_infinite_mapping)
        return tcp_send_head(meta_sk);

    skb = skb_peek(&mpcb->reinject_queue);

    if (skb)
        *reinject = 1;
    else
        skb = tcp_send_head(meta_sk);
    return skb;
}

static struct sk_buff *mptcp_rr_next_segment(struct sock *meta_sk,
                         int *reinject,
                         struct sock **subsk,
                         unsigned int *limit)
{
    const struct mptcp_cb *mpcb = tcp_sk(meta_sk)->mpcb;
    struct sock *choose_sk = NULL;
    struct mptcp_tcp_sock *mptcp;
    struct sk_buff *skb = __mptcp_rr_next_segment(meta_sk, reinject);
    unsigned char split = num_segments;
    unsigned char iter = 0, full_subs = 0;

    /* As we set it, we have to reset it as well. */
    *limit = 0;

    if (!skb)
        return NULL;

    if (*reinject) {
        *subsk = rr_get_available_subflow(meta_sk, skb, false);
        if (!*subsk)
            return NULL;

        return skb;
    }

retry:

    /* First, we look for a subflow who is currently being used */
    mptcp_for_each_sub(mpcb, mptcp) {
        struct sock *sk_it = mptcp_to_sock(mptcp);
        struct tcp_sock *tp_it = tcp_sk(sk_it);
        struct rrsched_priv *rr_p = rrsched_get_priv(tp_it);

        if (!mptcp_rr_is_available(sk_it, skb, false, cwnd_limited))
            continue;

        iter++;

        /* Is this subflow currently being used? */
        if (rr_p->quota > 0 && rr_p->quota < num_segments) {
            split = num_segments - rr_p->quota;
            choose_sk = sk_it;
            goto found;
        }

        /* Or, it's totally unused */
        if (!rr_p->quota) {
            split = num_segments;
            choose_sk = sk_it;
        }

        /* Or, it must then be fully used  */
        if (rr_p->quota >= num_segments)
            full_subs++;
    }

    /* All considered subflows have a full quota, and we considered at
     * least one.
     */
    if (iter && iter == full_subs) {
        /* So, we restart this round by setting quota to 0 and retry
         * to find a subflow.
         */
        mptcp_for_each_sub(mpcb, mptcp) {
            struct sock *sk_it = mptcp_to_sock(mptcp);
            struct tcp_sock *tp_it = tcp_sk(sk_it);
            struct rrsched_priv *rr_p = rrsched_get_priv(tp_it);

            if (!mptcp_rr_is_available(sk_it, skb, false, cwnd_limited))
                continue;

            rr_p->quota = 0;
        }

        goto retry;
    }

found:
    if (choose_sk) {
        unsigned int mss_now;
        struct tcp_sock *choose_tp = tcp_sk(choose_sk);
        struct rrsched_priv *rr_p = rrsched_get_priv(choose_tp);

        if (!mptcp_rr_is_available(choose_sk, skb, false, true))
            return NULL;

        *subsk = choose_sk;
        mss_now = tcp_current_mss(*subsk);
        *limit = split * mss_now;

        if (skb->len > mss_now)
            rr_p->quota += DIV_ROUND_UP(skb->len, mss_now);
        else
            rr_p->quota++;

        return skb;
    }

    return NULL;
}

static struct mptcp_sched_ops mptcp_sched_rr = {
    .get_subflow = rr_get_available_subflow,
    .next_segment = mptcp_rr_next_segment,
    .name = "roundrobin",
    .owner = THIS_MODULE,
};

static int __init rr_register(void)
{
    BUILD_BUG_ON(sizeof(struct rrsched_priv) > MPTCP_SCHED_SIZE);

    if (mptcp_register_scheduler(&mptcp_sched_rr))
        return -1;

    return 0;
}

static void rr_unregister(void)
{
    mptcp_unregister_scheduler(&mptcp_sched_rr);
}

module_init(rr_register);
module_exit(rr_unregister);

MODULE_AUTHOR("Christoph Paasch");
MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");
MODULE_DESCRIPTION("ROUNDROBIN MPTCP");
MODULE_VERSION("0.89");`
```

please help with this part of the code i didn't understand what it does can any one help me with understanding it ? :

```
    struct rrsched_priv {
    unsigned char quota;
};

static struct rrsched_priv *rrsched_get_priv(const struct tcp_sock *tp)
{
    return (struct rrsched_priv *)&tp->mptcp->mptcp_sched[0];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The Multipath TCP Scheduler is responsible for chosing in which subflow a packet will be forward and transmited. In the round-robin case, this choice is "random" for each subflow available and the following code is basically a constructor that regards the linux kernel tcp stack given by `tcp_sock` and the mptcp stack given by `net/mptcp.h`.

In the following code, there's a constructor regarding quota. It means the amount of packets that will be consume by each subflow.

```
    struct rrsched_priv {
    unsigned char quota; 
};
```

1. At the next step, `rrsched_priv` is taking linux-kernel `tcp_sock` attributes.
2. Then, the reference `*tp` is taking `mptcp->mptcp_sched[0]` from the mptcp stack;
3. Finally it returns as an `struct` for `rrsched_priv`

```
static struct rrsched_priv *rrsched_get_priv(const struct tcp_sock *tp)
{
    return (struct rrsched_priv *)&tp->mptcp->mptcp_sched[0];
}
```

### References

[Round-Robin Scheduler] : http://progmp.net/progmp.html#/dissertation_round_robin

[tcp_sock] : https://docs.huihoo.com/doxygen/linux/kernel/3.7/structtcp__sock.html

[Quota] : https://tuprints.ulb.tu-darmstadt.de/7709/13/Dissertation_Froemmgen.pdf

[MPTCP Scheduler] : http://progmp.net/